# How to define User defined buttons in alert for Rhomobile Application

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I have been using WebView.execute_js() to popup some message or data as like below

```
WebView.execute_js("alert('"+message+"')")
```

But our client had specified to have custom buttons for the alert box. Do we have any way to make this success.

Please make some sample code, as i'm totally new to this framework.

Thanks

Comment: check this http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#alerts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Alert.show_popup()` to accomplish this requirement.

```
Alert.show_popup( {
    :message => 'Some message', 
    :title => 'Custom title', 
    :icon => '/public/images/icon.png',
    :buttons => ["Yes", "No"] } )
```

Hope this helps you in brief http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#alerts